# building a cortana skill to take a picture

Tags: node.js, botframework, cortana-skills-kit

i am trying to build a Cortana skill to be able to take a picture using the surface camera. how to do that? currently my skill is able to do question answers using the bot framework and using nodejs. code looks like

```
bot.dialog('ScanCardDialog', function(session){
    <what need to be done to take a picture? goes here>
}).triggerAction({ matches: /(\w)+ (card)/i});
```

Comment: Unfortunately, as far as I can tell, the most you can do is tell Cortana to speak via the Bot Framework. This [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cortana/skills/overview) don't seem to show any way to interact with the camera.

Answer (score 1):

The only way you can do that is if you have a companion [UWP app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cortana/voice-commands/interact-with-a-background-app-in-cortana) that can take a picture. Cortana skills can [deep-link to a UWP app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cortana/voice-commands/deep-link-into-your-app-from-cortana) but **cannot access the device camera yet**. Hope this helps!!